# @Override for interface methods causes JSP compilation to fail

Tags: java, jsp, annotations, weblogic-10.x

For some reason, putting `@Override` on methods overriding interface methods causes JSP compilation to fail in weblogic. Everything is definitely running off of `JDK 1.6.0_14`, but this Java 5'ism still persists.

Oddly, JSP compilation occasionally fails with a stacktrace pointing at code not necessarily obviously used by the JSP itself.

What's going on here?

Comment: Which version of the JSP spec does Weblogic 10 support?

Comment: It's just telling you that JSP is the wrong place for the job.

Comment: Are you putting that Annotation in the JSP file itself?

Comment: The JSP compilation fails due to annotation errors in code not related to the JSP.

Comment: Maybe Weblogic is configured to compile the JSPs using a Java 5 JDK or to compile them into Java 5 class files?

Comment: Any idea on WHERE that would be configured? That's kind of the thought I had too, but I have no idea where to start looking. I'm not a weblogic guy.

Comment: @Stefan Neither am I...sorry. :(

Comment: What OS are you running under? If Windows, check that the Java installer didn't add any java*.exe files under Windows\System32 directory that may be conflicting with WebLogic runtime. Though, I don't believe there's and JDK references in there, just JRE.

Comment: It is most likely what @mangst is saying, that Weblogic is configured using Java 5

Comment: @Shervin: Something is obviously using Java 5 somewhere. But where?

Comment: @Stefan Kendall I don't know how WebLogic is configured, but what you should do is search for JAVA, or JAVA_HOME within the WebLogic folder. There should be some configuration file where that is located.

Comment: I would assume from your question that in your JSP you are doing something similar to this?
<code><pre>
<%!
    @Override
    public int someMethod(int i) {
        return 1;
    }
%>
</pre></code>
If so, putting code blocks in JSP is just bad practice anyhow.

Comment: Mondain: No. You clearly didn't read my question, and you're contributing nothing by saying "you shouldn't do it anyhow." If any JAVA code accessed from a JSP (perhaps a model, or just some pojo) happens to have @Override on an interface method, the JSP recompilation fails. As a poster below pointed out, this is due to the Javelin JSP recompilation engine being enabled in weblogic.

Comment: According to this, at least Weblogic 10.3 is required to use Java 6: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=884263.  I don't see you are using Weblogic 10, but I don't see the minor rev anywhere (I could be missing it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @Override is supposed to only be retained in source so shouldn't come up in byte code.  There might an angle you can play in ensuring those classes are complied separately from the JSPs and simply available in the classpath -- rather than the source path.

If that's already the case then it might be a different issue than what is immediately showing.

Used to be the JSP complier was a separate library shipped with the server and not tied to the vm the server is running in.  WLS used to use Javelin.  Seems like they switched that in 10 to use the [Java Compiler API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=199).  So it should work fine as long as you have Sun vm Java 1.6.  But if there's 'javelin' anything in your stacktrace, definitely check that angle.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look for this. Most of our WLS installations were upgrades, I believe, or had WLS9 installed at some point, so this could be the culprit.

Comment: Javelin is definitely running. How do I switch?

Comment: It looks like JavelinxJSPStub is in weblogic.jar. How can I possibly disable this?

Comment: Not too sure there.  They mention the switch in their release notes:  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/notes/new.html#wp1090981

Comment: I know. I found that too :(. Reality seems to disconnect from the docs, however.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this a lot myself. In Java 6, it is (supposedly) permissible to use @Override on interface implementation methods. In Java 5, this is an error. However in my Java 6 code, sometimes @Override is accepted on interface implementation methods, and sometimes it is not.

To make things weirder, some IDEs (e.g. NetBeans) are fine with it, while IntelliJ IDEA is sometimes ok and sometimes not. I have found, however, that compiling the code in either IDE will ignore the alleged errors being reported by the IDE.

In other words, is the problem manifesting in your IDE? If so, compile the code directly (use the command-line if necessary) and see what happens. The IDE may be reporting spurious errors.

Comment: No, this is a real issue in JSP compilation. If the JSP (under weblogic) touches any code that overrides an interface method, the JSP will not be able to compile and render.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround might be to precompile JSP using [`appc`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/ejb/appc_ejbc.html). This could at least allow to circumvent the issue.

Regarding the "real" question, my understanding is that you did upgrade domains, so maybe have a look at the following resources:

- Web Applications, JSPs, and Servlets

  - [Backwards Compatibility Flags](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/upgrade/compat.html#wp1121144)
- Procedure for Upgrading a WebLogic Domain

  - [Select Upgrade Options](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/upgrade/upgrade_dom.html#wp1084822) (related to domain upgrade)
- [Backward Compatibility Flags](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/upgrade/compat.html#wp1125284)

  - `JSPCompilerBackwardsCompatible` - Specifies whether to allow JSPs that do not comply with the JSP 2.0 specification

This is a wild guess but maybe some backward compatibility flag is activated and WebLogic keeps using the "old" approach.

Comment: I was hoping the flag for JSPCompilerBackwardsCompatible would do it, but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your instinct and the other answers that WLS is using Java 5 somehere.  The items below seem like useful tidbits from Oracle/WebLogic resources.  I don't have a WebLogic  Server 10.3 installation to confirm these:

### Weblogic Server 10.3

According to this, at least Weblogic Server 10.3 is required to use Java 6, but I can't see anything the confirms this as authoritative info:

- http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=884263

> Re: WebLogic 10.0 supports Java 6?
>   Posted: Apr 9, 2009 12:26 PM     in response to: user8324142
>   Hi,
>   Weblogic 10 will not support JDK6.
>   Please upgrade to Weblogic 10.3 to work with JDK 6.

### Checking the Java version

- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/common/docs103/install/postins.html#wp1090736

> **Determining Which JDK Version You Are Using**
>
> You can determine which version of the JDK you are using by issuing a command, as follows:
>
> 1. Open a command prompt window and go to the appropriate directory:
>      BEA_HOME\WL_HOME\server\bin (Windows)
>      BEA_HOME/WL_HOME/server/bin (UNIX)
>
>    In both pathnames, BEA_HOME represents the directory in which you have installed your software and WL_HOME represents the wlserver_< version >.
> 2. Make sure that your environment is set up properly by entering the following command at the prompt:
>      setWLSenv.cmd (Windows)
>      setWLSenv.sh (UNIX)
> 3. Enter the following command at the prompt:
>      java -version

### Configuring Java version:

- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/perform/WLSTuning.html

> **Setting Java Parameters for Starting WebLogic Server**
>
> ... Java parameters must be specified whenever you start WebLogic Server. ... Oracle recommends that you incorporate the command into a [startup] script ...
>
> If you used the Configuration Wizard to create your domain, the WebLogic startup scripts are located in the domain-name directory where you specified your domain. By default, this directory is BEA_HOME\user_projects\domain\domain-name, where BEA_HOME is the directory that contains the product installation, and domain-name is the name of the domain directory defined by the selected configuration template. ...
>
> Change the value of the variable JAVA_HOME to the location of your JDK. For example:
>   `set JAVA_HOME=C:\bea\jdk150_03`
>
> ...

Answer (score -2):

In my mind, `@Override` makes sense on methods that are overriding methods, not implementing methods.

So if you have an interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

A class that *implements* that interface is below (`MyClassA`):

```
public MyClassA implements MyInterface {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("This is from MyClassA");
    }
}
```

Then, the below class extends `MyClassA` and *overrides* `doSomething`, and so then I'd add the `@Override` annotation.

```
public MyClassB extends MyClassA implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("This is from MyClassB");
    }
}
```

I wouldn't do the below (whether or not it is permissable) in any case, since it breaks the idea about overriding something - you're implementing, not overriding the interface:

```
public MyClassA implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("This is from MyClassA");
    }
}
```

Comment: So you shouldn't throw @Override when extending abstract classes? Using @Override allows you to ensure you're blowing away whatever you got from something up the inheritance tree, instead of creating a new definition. The most notorious example of this is creating an incorrect "equals" method that takes an object of type A vs type Object. This problem occurs EVERYWHERE you rely on inheritance to override/implement a method. @Override gives you the guarantee that you're doing what you think you're doing.

Comment: Overriding an abstract class is very different to implementing an interface. My example shows when using interfaces (not abstract classes). You mentioned interfaces, not abstract classes; i.e. I thought you were only implementing an interface, which could cause an issue if the @Override annotation is used.

Comment: If I have an abstract class that has methods which need to be implemented, but it also implements an interface, I can immediately see and be sure which methods are from the interface with compile-time checking with @Override. I get no such checks without the annotation. Regardless, this syntax is perfectly valid in JDK6 and it shouldn't cause my JSPs to fail.

Comment: Sure. But you did say overriding on 'interface' implementation methods, but didn't mention the abstract class ;) I think that led to the confusion and my answer...